# Why is there a difference in placement of the prayer "Avinu Malkeinu"?

Tags: tefilla, nusach-ashkenaz, nusach-sefard

Nusach Ashkenaz places the prayer *Avinu Malkeinu* immediately after the repetition of the Amidah while Nusach Sefard places it in the middle of *Tachanun* (between the first paragraph *Vayomer David* and *Shomer Yisra'el*).

What is the reason for the difference of its placement?

Comment: There are definitely nusach sefard places I’ve been to that start with Avinu malkeinu, followed by vidui and the rest of tachanun